# removing Tails USB: Effect on computer

Tags: tails

If you remove a Tails USB from your computer, which is running from the Tails USB, will it factory reset your computer or delete all the memory that was already on the computer before Tails?

Answer (score 0):

Removing Tails USB will only erase the "volatile" memory ([RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory)), and will not affect your hard drive or any other storage.